# If $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f=1$ then prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+f(x)}=\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Given that $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is  a measurable function.

If $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f=1$ then prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+f(x)}=\infty$

Any hints on how to proceed with this problem

Following your notes

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+f}\geq \int 1-\int f=1.measure (\mathbb R)-1=\infty$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1+f} = 1 - \frac{f}{1+f} \ge 1 - f$$

Comment: Yes, it is essentially like that. If you want to be more formal, you can replace the $1 - f$ on the RHS by $s - f$ where $s$ is a step function $s(x) = \begin{cases}1,& |x| < L,\\0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. This will allow you to show your integral is $\ge 2L-1$ for any $L$ and hence it must diverge.

Comment: You can do a proof by contradiction, using the inequality provided by @achillehui

Comment: There is nothing wrong about your argument, it is also fine to use it in a competitive exam. It just seems to be me you are not that confident in dealing with those infinities and I offer you an alternative approach not to deal with the infinities directly.